# No output being shown on Mobile Screen in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to run an app with the code on my android studio there is no error the app runs on the device **doesn't show output** I have shared a screenshot of it

[image: java file]
[image: XML code]
[image: manifest file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not Overriding the `onCreate` method. Try this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.relative_layout);
```

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

You should try to read the warning of the xml file maybe that will help you to understand your problem, sometimes that's also happened with me but I solve these UI problems by looking and reading warning.

You should also add your code of the activity in the questions its easy to read and understand.